# How to implement same action with transition and without transition ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any solution to use same action with transition and without transition?

**css**

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
```

**jquery**

```
$("#transition").click(function(){
    $("#box-progress").css("left", "50%");
});
// This shoudn't show transition;
$("#no-transition").click(function(){
    $("#box-progress").css("left", "50%");
});
```

Demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/XcRNd/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Put the transitions in a separate class, like:

```
.apply_transitions {
    /* .. */
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

Then, you want the transition do:

```
$("#box-progress").addClass("apply_transitions").css("left", "50%");
```

And if you don't want the transtion, do:

```
$("#box-progress").removeClass("apply_transitions").css("left", "50%");
```

---

This means that by default, nothing has a transition unless you add the `apply_transitions` class.